# Drawing random numbers from TransformedDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

Suppose I have created the following `TransformedDistribution`:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[0.5` + 4.830917874396135` Sqrt[0.01071225` - 10 x^2],
    x \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[α, β], Assumptions -> {x >= 0}]
```

My question is simply, how do I get Mathematica to draw random numbers from dist?

Edit:

Should this, for example, work?

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[0.5 + 4.830917874396135 Sqrt[0.01071225 - 10 x^2], 
  x \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[5.389705454315603, 0.00517629198314588], 
  Assumptions -> {x > 0 , x < 0.1}]

RandomVariate[dist, 10]
```

It doesn't at my end.

Comment: You have to specify [\[Alpha] and  \[Beta] to this end.After that RandomVariate should do the job.

Comment: you will get complex values unless you specify an upper bound for `x`;  is that ok?

Comment: @kglrThat is fine, yes.

Comment: Should this, for example, be working?

    RandomVariate[TransformedDistribution[
  0.5` + 4.830917874396135` Sqrt[0.01071225` - 10 \[FormalX]^2], \[FormalX] \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[5.389705454315603`, 0.00517629198314588`], Assumptions -> {x > 0, x < 0.1`}], 10]

Answer (score 1):

`Assumptions` in `TransformedDistribution` (afaik) can be used to specify constraints on the parameters, not on the random variable that is being transformed. You can truncate `x` to positive values using `TruncatedDistribution` as follows:

```
ClearAll[dist]
dist[α_?NumericQ, β_?NumericQ] :=  TransformedDistribution[
   0.5` + 4.830917874396135` Sqrt[0.01071225` - 10 x^2], 
  Distributed[x, TruncatedDistribution[{0, ∞},  GammaDistribution[α, β]]]]

RandomVariate[dist[2, 3], 5]
```

> {0.5 + 16.63336711175035 I, 0.5 + 98.68263490369695 I, 
>    0.5 + 32.25820066988831 I, 0.5 + 60.43892062767867 I, 
>    0.5 + 104.61100104210925 I}