# SmoothHistogram as "Probability"?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

In a previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183314/drawing-random-numbers-from-transformeddistribution), the following answer was given:

```
ClearAll[dist] 
dist[α_?NumericQ, β_?NumericQ] :=
 TransformedDistribution[0.5` + 4.830917874396135` Sqrt[0.01071225` - 10 x^2], 
  Distributed[x, TruncatedDistribution[{0, 0.02135225}, GammaDistribution[α, β]]]]
```

and

```
H = RandomVariate[dist[7.788017927062043, 0.0011475109935367525], 5000]
```

did indeed provide what I was looking for. Except the last step. The last step is to use `SmoothHistogram` on $H$ and present the data in terms of `"Probability"`. However, reading up on `SmoothHistogram`, `"PDF"`, `"CF"` and so on are options, but not `"Probability"`.

So, how can I show the output of `SmoothHistogram` as `"Probability"`?

The actual data I am using is:

```
   s1 =  {0.990009, 0.985514, 0.985514, 0.977022, 0.990509, 0.976523, 0.98201, 0.965034, 0.982517, 0.962537, 0.96903, 0.990009, 0.983016, 0.992007, 0.983016, 0.991508, 0.97952, 0.977522, 0.975524, 0.982017, 0.983016, 0.987012, 0.968531, 0.930569, 0.990509, 0.975024, 0.962037, 0.984015, 0.985514, 0.976023, 0.984515, 0.974025, 0.973526, 0.985014, 0.978021, 0.976523, 0.982517, 0.962037, 0.982017, 0.976523, 0.961538, 0.978521, 0.986013, 0.983016, 0.98951, 0.98951, 0.991008, 0.968031, 0.992507, 0.980519, 0.975024, 0.978521, 0.973026, 0.984515, 0.981018, 0.985514, 0.98901, 0.983016, 0.988511, 0.985014, 0.983516, 0.981018, 0.980019, 0.984015, 0.986513, 0.994005, 0.981518, 0.948051, 0.983516, 0.982517, 0.976023, 0.982517, 0.972527, 0.986513, 0.97952, 0.971028, 0.978021, 0.974025, 0.970029, 0.983516, 0.986513, 0.990509, 0.964035, 0.961538, 0.982517, 0.986513, 0.966533, 0.975024, 0.982517, 0.97952, 0.961538, 0.968031, 0.993506, 0.978021, 0.910589, 0.962537, 0.93906, 0.967032, 0.958541, 0.971028, 0.970029, 0.954545, 0.983016, 0.983016, 0.960039, 0.938061, 0.978021, 0.961038, 0.986513, 0.983016, 0.96953, 0.976023, 0.982517, 0.977522, 0.977022, 0.946053, 0.953546, 0.951048, 0.942557, 0.956043, 0.946053, 0.923076, 0.98901, 0.987012, 0.999, 0.985014, 0.986513, 0.983016, 0.994505, 0.986013, 0.995004, 0.995004, 0.993506, 0.988011, 0.986013, 0.985514, 0.988511, 0.991008, 0.974525, 0.992007, 0.987012, 0.971528, 0.985014, 0.990509, 0.994005, 0.988511, 0.98901, 0.988511, 0.992007, 0.98901, 0.992007, 0.991508, 0.991008, 0.985514, 0.985514, 0.987012, 0.98901, 0.97902, 0.983016, 0.987012, 0.981518, 0.98951, 0.995504, 0.986513, 0.985014, 0.971028, 0.974525, 0.97902, 0.975524, 0.987012, 0.988511, 0.997002, 0.972027, 0.987512, 0.984515, 0.977522, 0.974525, 0.975024, 0.973526, 0.986013, 0.982017, 0.966033, 0.967032, 0.951548, 0.966533, 0.984515, 0.984515, 0.985514, 0.986013, 0.984515, 0.986513, 0.986513, 0.987012, 0.993506, 0.987512, 0.992507, 0.98901, 0.986513, 0.984515, 0.988511, 0.985014, 0.995504, 0.981018, 0.990509, 0.996503, 0.991508, 0.996003, 0.968531, 0.992007, 0.988011, 0.992007, 0.996503, 0.991008, 0.985514, 0.990509, 0.986513, 0.994505, 0.998001, 0.988011, 0.996003, 0.988011, 0.981518, 0.987512, 0.984015, 0.986013, 0.993506, 0.985514, 0.987512, 0.983516, 0.986513, 0.984515, 0.956043, 0.996503, 0.984015, 0.992007, 0.987012, 0.996003, 0.907592, 0.996003, 0.999}
```

Comment: I am not sure what probability would even mean in this case ... A histogram is discrete. It has bins. It makes sense to ask the probability that a data point falls in a certain bin. SmoothHistogram is inherently continuous, thus probability makes no sense. Only probability density does. Voting to close as the question is due to a mathematical misunderstanding.

Comment: That is true. My problem is that I have a Histogram (as you say, discrete) that I would like to overlay with the smooth curve given by $dist$ where probability is on the y axis. Thinking about what you say, I guess that is not possible.

Comment: Instead of using `SmoothHistogram`, you could compute a `SmoothKernelDistribution`, then `Plot` the `PDF` of its output with an appropriate scaling factor (i.e. the bin width) to match the binned histogram.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'd argue the other way around:  Get a `PDF` from both and stick with the `PDF` (no other scaling).  The "Probability" option for `Histogram` gives relative frequencies (which is far better than using the default `Counts` as that accounts for different sample sizes).  I think that one almost always wants (or should want) a vertical axis for a histogram that is independent of the sample size.  If one is interested in estimated probability density function, then probability density should be the vertical axis.  (And I agree that `Probability` makes no sense if there are no bins.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `"PDF"` as the third argument for both `Histogram` and `SmoothHistogram` ... and then, ***if you have to***, you can rescale the vertical axis to "`Probability"` values:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[dist[7.788017927062043, 0.0011475109935367525], 5000];
colors = {LightBlue, Green};
{hist1, hist2} =  Histogram[data, Automatic, #, 
     ChartStyle -> Last[colors = RotateRight[colors]], PlotLabel -> #,
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] & /@ {"PDF", "Probability"};
shist = SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]];


Row[{Show[hist1, ImageSize -> 300], Show[hist1, shist, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

We first find the scaling factor using the maximum heights in `hist1` and `hist2`:

```
scale = Divide @@ (Max[Cases[#[[1]], Rectangle[{_, _}, {_, h_}, ___] :> h, ∞]] & /@ 
   {hist1, hist2});
```

Since the scaling of the vertical axis is linear, we can simply re-scale the tick labels using `` Charting`FindTicks ``:

```
Row[{Show[hist2, ImageSize -> 300], 
  Show[hist1, shist, Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{0, scale}, {0, 1}]},
     PlotLabel -> "Probability", ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using `data = s1` we get the following pictures:

```
Row[{Show[hist1, ImageSize -> 300], Show[hist1, shist, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

```
Row[{Show[hist2, ImageSize -> 300], 
  Show[hist1, shist, Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{0, scale}, {0, 1}]}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Probability", ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for "if you have to" (although the rest of the answer is good, too).

Comment: Thank you @JimB.

Comment: @kglr I must admit I am having trouble implementing your solution using my actual data. Could you please show me how the code changes given my data, which I have added in an edit?

Comment: @user120911, the only change you need to do is to replace the second line with `data = s1`. I posted the pictures you should get when you do this replacement.